# Is there any other platform to check contract working?

Tags: contract-development, ether, contract-invocation, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am trying from past few days but didn't get test ether to test my own contract...is there any other platform where I can test my contract or can you send me some ether

```
0x0aB6F803A232a9cd595efB9eaf496415Bb7E52e8
```

Comment: Test it in a private network

Comment: How to do that ??

Answer (score 1):

You can download testRCP (repo https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) and run a local node on your PC, then set up Remix to run on your local node.

Setting remix:

- On 'Contract' - 'Environment' choose Web3Provider and then set http://127.0.0.1:8545 (http://localhost:8545 won't work)

Once you deployed your contract on your local node just go to MEW (MyEtherWallet) https://www.myetherwallet.com/ and on the top-right you can choose which node MEW should connect to.

Define your own custom node:

[image]

Set up the node:

[image]

**N.B: testRPC must be running on your PC or this won't work.**

Now if all went well the account displayed in your testRPC console should be accessible, with the private key, through MEW.

[image]

Hope it helps. Come back if you have doubts.

Check this for more info: https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/how-can-i-connect-to-a-custom-node

Answer (score 0):

Remix is an online solidity compiler which lets you deploy contract online and there is another online solidity IDE youn can use that too.