# How to include solidity file into another?

Tags: solidity, solc

I completely stuck on modules importing into Solidity contract. Here is my files/directory layout:

```
.
|-> contracts/
  |-> contract1.sol
  |-> contract2.sol
```

File `contract1.sol` contains only `pragma` and `import` statements like:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
import "./contract2" as c2;
```

File `contract2.sol` conntains only `pragma` statement:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
```

Then I open `node` shell and input following code:

```
> solc = require('solc')
> solc.compile(fs.readFileSync('contracts/contract1.sol').toString())
{ contracts: {},
  errors: [ ':3:1: ParserError: Source "contract2" not found: File not supplied initially.\nimport "./contract2" as c2;\n^-------------------------^\n' ],
  sourceList: [ '' ],
  sources: {} }
```

I already tried to:

- specify full path in `contract1.sol`
- add extension `.sol`
- remove `./contracts/` prefix and run commands inside `contracts` folder.

Nothing works. Accordingly to [this article](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/layout-of-source-files.html#paths) begin import with dot and slash is enough but, damn, no!

How to include one `sol` file into another?
Node version is 8.1.13, solcjs version is 0.4.13+commit.0fb4cb1a.Emscripten.clang

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I deployed a contract using web3js sometime back and I faced the similar problem, I fixed it by defining all dependent contract in an input object and then compiled it.

You can take a look at this code for reference -

https://gist.github.com/inovizz/1fdc2af0182584b90008e0cf2895554c

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, man! If you'll be in Thailand let me know buy you a beer! You saved me from madness. Of course, it works.

One question: could you give me recommendation, I just started to work with smart contracts, should I follow this way (I mean using web3 and other "low level" components) or better use Truffle?

Comment: I prefer truffle, it makes life easier :D

Comment: Truffle is very useful, but for starting with solidity I recommend you to use remix online IDE connected to a local node (just like testRPC); then set up MEW to run on your node for testing your contracts with external txs. Check this out for more info:https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/how-can-i-connect-to-a-custom-node

Or even this post: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16740/is-there-any-other-platform-to-check-contract-working/21172#21172