# How to use Solidity solc to compile A.sol that imports B.sol file?

Tags: solidity, nodejs, solc, ethereumj, import

I know how to install solc via "npm install --save solc"
then use solc.compile to compile one sol file. But now I've got A.sol file that imports B.sol file, and when I run node compile.js, no error in my terminal, but no json file is generated!

But when I use the same compile.js to compiile B.sol, it works. Why??? How to fix this importing feature in Solidity sol files??? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const pathA = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'A.sol');
//to find the path of A.sol inside the folder 'contract' in your project
const pathB = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'B.sol');
const solA = fs.readFileSync(pathA, 'utf8');
const solB = fs.readFileSync(pathB, 'utf8');

const input = {
  sources: {
    'A.sol': solA,
    'B.sol': solB
  }
};
console.log(solc.compile(input, 1));
```

Comment: For those Googling, you may see an error to the effect of: `Source "<contract>.sol" not found: File import callback not supported` before implementing the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Add them as sources yes but also add a import callback if using solcjs.

https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js/issues/114#issuecomment-354752466

Answer (score 1):

I am using `@remix-project/remix-solidity` on browser, it works great for me

Simply call:

```
const response = await compile(
                {
                    [CONTRACT_FILE_NAME]: {
                        content: source
                    }
                }
                , {
                    version: SOLIDITY_COMPILER_VERSION
                }, handleNpmImport) as CompilerAbstract;
```

Source code : https://github.com/vanduc1102/samples/blob/master/reactjs/cra-solidity-etherjs/package.json

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to get solc js to import .sol files into eachother - I'm not sure if it's possible. My workaround is to just combine all .sol files into one single file and compile that.

[See this question.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21206/how-to-include-solidity-file-into-another)